# Java Connect Perforce Using the Keys

Tags: automation, devops, build-automation, p4java

My Requirement is I want to connect to a perforce server "abc.def.com:1689" to access it requires my public and private key (identity basically) Now I want to achieve same using the Java Program.

I want to connect to the Perforce server and perform actions programmatically its not a username and password base model it uses the private key to authenticate user and allow access to the repository.

Can someone guide me on this I have already tried few suggestions mentioned in the other stackoverflow links but its not working.

```
String uri = "p4javassl://abc.def.com:1689";
            IOptionsServer server = ServerFactory.getOptionsServer(uri, null);
            server.addTrust("somefingerPrint");
            server.connect();
            IServerInfo sInfo = server.getServerInfo();
            System.out.println("user "+sInfo.getUserName());
```

com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException: Unable to connect to Perforce server

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to authenticate to a Helix server with a client cert.   That's not possible.

The Perforce/Helix server **always** needs a user for authorization as file/resource protections are based on your user.   You will always need to set your user:

```
server.setUserName('Vikki');
```

Comment: I have a username but firstly I need to connect to the Helix Server through the identity certificate and then other information like fetching file or other perforce action

Comment: What's the whole exception and stack trace.

Comment: Also, on the machine where you are running java, install the p4 command line.  Then run "p4 -p ssl:abc.def.com:1689 info"   What does that return?  If you can't connect to the helix server with the p4 command line then you can't connect using P4Java.